# How to make production build for electron + react js + next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, desktop-application, next.js

I'm using electron with react js and next. I can't find how to make it's production build. Can anyone help me in this with all steps.
My project structure is :

- app
- node_modules
- pages
- routes
- static
- package.json
- main.js (entry points for electron)
- next.config.js

  My folder structure doesn't include any renderer folder.

Answer (score 11):

There are two examples in the official Next.js repo here for JavaScript and TypeScript:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron-typescript

They have a good file/folder structure which you can use to start your project with!